# React native AsyncStorage has weird \\ stuff

Tags: react-native, react-redux, asyncstorage

I use React native.

And When I get storage data from AsyncStorage as below.

```
const keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
const result = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys);
const stringResult = result.toString();
console.log(stringResult);
```

The result has weird `\\` stuffs like below.

```
persist:root,{"usersReducer":"{\"isLoggedIn\":true,\"token\":\"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6NiwiaWF0IjoxNjU3MTI5MDEwfQ.iA2AsFXuKMNAM1vgrPswjdCU46PemIu771SDqWKWqAw\"}","_persist":"{\"version\":-1,\"rehydrated\":true}"}
```

I use `redux-persist` so that it has 'persist:root' in front, i guess.

Anyway that make me not able to get data with this code:
**await AsyncStorage.getItem("isLoggedIn")**

Why does it has `\`? When I store data I don't put that things.

Comment: happens due to stringifying of JSON .try to JSON.parse it

Comment: @ShahVipul If I do this `const stringResult = JSON.parse(result.toString());` then result says : JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "persist"

Comment: first remove .toString() and then try .may work.OR JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(result)) OR vice versa JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result))

Comment: no they all don't work.

result of `const parseResult = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));`

Array [
  Array [
    "persist:root",
    "{\"usersReducer\":\"{\\\"isLoggedIn\\\":true,\\\"token\\\":\\\"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6NiwiaWF0IjoxNjU3MTI5MDEwfQ.iA2AsFXuKMNAM1vgrPswjdCU46PemIu771SDqWKWqAw\\\"}\",\"_persist\":\"{\\\"version\\\":-1,\\\"rehydrated\\\":true}\"}",
  ],

Comment: result of `const parseResult = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(result));`
=> JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "persist"

Comment: const stringResult = result // can you tell it's output without .toString()

Comment: Array [
  Array [
    "persist:root",
    "{\"usersReducer\":\"{\\\"isLoggedIn\\\":true,\\\"token\\\":\\\"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6NiwiaWF0IjoxNjU3MTI5MDEwfQ.iA2AsFXuKMNAM1vgrPswjdCU46PemIu771SDqWKWqAw\\\"}\",\"_persist\":\"{\\\"version\\\":-1,\\\"rehydrated\\\":true}\"}",
  ],
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the data from below code..

```
const keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
const result = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys);
const modifiedResult = result.flat().splice(1);
const parseResult = JSON.parse(
  JSON.parse(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(modifiedResult)).toString())
    .usersReducer
);
const { isLoggedIn } = parseResult;
```

I do multiple x2 JSON.parse and JSON.stringify 
not sure it is right way or not.
Anyway value is extracted correctly.